# Tkinter button background color is not working in mac os

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tkinter-layout, tkinter-button

I am trying to change the **bg color of a tkinter button** on my mac (catalina) but instead of getting a colored background, it is showing a blank white space in the layout.

The button code I used:

```py
button_open = Button(root, width=45, bg="#82CC6C", fg="black", text="OPEN",
                     highlightbackground="#82CC6C", highlightthickness=1,
                     borderwidth=0.2, relief="groove", padx=0, pady=0)
    
button_open.grid()
```

Result I am getting:

[image: Error button]

What I expected:

[image: Expected rersult]

I tried changing all the parameters but it is always giving me the same result,

How can we fix this? Is it a **bug in tkinter on mac only**?

Comment: I got the fix: Use tkmacosx module for tkinter buttons in mac, use "from tkmacosx import Button", and then change the parameters and use borderless=1 to remove the unnecessary layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the fix:

Use [tkmacosx](https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/) module for tkinter buttons in mac, use `from tkmacosx import Button` and then change the parameters and also add this parameter `borderless=1` to remove the unnecessary layout.
You can see the result I got after using this:

[image: MacOS screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for information on the same issue and it seems to be a limitation with tkinter using the MacOS APIs. Basically MacOS says the button colors can't change so tkinter can't change them.

https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88409

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Sonoma 14.1.2) no backgroun color is working on all widgets (Label,Buttons etc)

The solution I found is using the ttkbootstrap

```
if os.name == "posix":
    import ttkbootstrap as ttk  # woriking on mac
elif os.name == "nt":
    from tkinter import ttk  # working on windows
else:
    print("Don't know the system")
    sys.exit(-1)
```

And for use the button

```
s1 = ttk.Style().configure("custom.TButton", 
                           background="red")
button3 = ttk.Button(exercise_frame, 
                     text="Button 3", 
                     style="custom.TButton")
```