# TKinter can't change background color of window (MacOS M1 Max)

Tags: python, tkinter

For some reason I cannot change the background color of my window. it just appears black every time.
I have tried:

- `top.config(bg='blue')`
- `top.config(background='blue')`
- `top.configure(bg='blue')`
- `top.configure(background='blue')`
- `top['bg']='blue'`
- `top['background']='blue'`

Code: (Everything else works perfectly its just the background color)

```
def openWorkoutCustomization():
    top = Tk(className='Customize your Workout!')
    top.config(background="blue")
    top.title("Customize Your Workout!")
    top.geometry("900x600")

    variable = StringVar(top)
    variable.set(workout_list[0])

    w = OptionMenu(top, variable, *workout_list)
    w.pack()

    button = Button(top, text="Start", command= lambda: startWorkout(variable.get()))
    button.pack()

    top.mainloop()
```

Comment: try this may be work https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745312/8133524

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter button background color is not working in mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72056706/tkinter-button-background-color-is-not-working-in-mac-os)